# Is GoToAction's altitude is the absolute height?

Tags: android, dji-sdk

Two of GoToAction's constructors have an altitude attribute, is the altitude is an absolute height (x above sea level) or the height compared to his current location or the height compared to the take off location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the altitude is above takeoff.   All altitudes in the SDK ar based on takeoff altitude.